# A fake Snapchat account has been created in my name

Tags: identity-theft

A fake Snapchat account has been created in my name, and it is currently being misused.

How can I figure out who created it? Going to the cyber cell is a big task. I just want to know how I could get hold of the fake account's IP address.

Comment: Names are not unique.  What makes you think that this is in "your" name, and not somebody using their own?  For that matter, does snapchat even require that somebody use their "real" name, as opposed to something they just want to try out?  Also,

Comment: You should contact snapchat directly and explain to them your situation.They will make something,

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse we deal with that here too and usually don't shrug it off as a silly coincidence http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38466/how-to-handle-people-impersonating-other-people-by-choosing-the-same-display-nam

Comment: @djechlin the questions clockwork is asking are valid. There is not enough detail in the question for us to know exactly what is going on. What does "on my name" mean to the OP? If it is simply that a username is the same as the OP's name, that is not something we deal with.

Comment: Gotta ask, what's a "cyber cell"?  Is that a cybercrime investigation office? Ive never heard that term before (am from US)

Comment: @JeffMeden it appears "Cyber Cell" is part of a police department in India: http://www.keralapolice.org/newsite/email_cybercell.html  And presumably they're about as effective as the Internet Police: http://internetpolice.us/

Comment: Are they Snapchatting pictures of you?

Answer (score 24):

This kind of thing happens all too often, and there isn't much you can do about it. You aren't going to get ahold of the person's IP address, or be able to find out anything beyond what is on the public snapchat account profile. Snapchat could determine a lot more, for instance IP address and the email address used when creating the account. They are not going to give you this information though, and even if they did give you the IP it's not good enough to tell for certain who the perpetrator is, especially if they are using TOR or a shared IP address.

Your best bet is to contact snapchat and tell them you are the victim of identity theft, and ask for the account to be closed. They will have a process for that.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40081/discussion-on-answer-by-gdd-a-fake-snapchat-account-has-been-created-in-my-name).